# Why are my cards stacking on top of each other?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to lay cards next to each other but they are stacking on top of each other.
The height of the cards div is 1.
I have tried changing padding, margin, tried putting height to 100%.
I dont know if my navbar is interfering in some way.

```
<div className="cards">
    <div className="row" style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <div className="col s6 m4">
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-image">
            <img
              src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/11/4a/54/fe/essence-restaurant.jpg"
              alt="restaurant one"
              width="500px"
              height="200px"
            />
            <span className="card-title">Card Title</span>
          </div>
          <div className="card-content">
            <p>
              I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of
              information. I am convenient because I require little markup
              to use effectively.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="card-action">
            <a href="#">This is a link</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="col s6 m4">
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-image">
            <img
              src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/11/4a/54/fe/essence-restaurant.jpg"
              alt="restaurant one"
              width="400px"
              height="200px"
            />
            <span className="card-title">Card Title</span>
          </div>
          <div className="card-content">
            <p>
              I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of
              information. I am convenient because I require little markup
              to use effectively.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="card-action">
            <a href="#">This is a link</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add `position: relative;` to your row class styles.

```css
.row {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div className="cards">
    <div class="row" style={ display: flex; position: relative;}>
      <div className="col s6 m4">
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-image">
            <img
              src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/11/4a/54/fe/essence-restaurant.jpg"
              alt="restaurant one"
              width="500px"
              height="200px"
            />
            <span className="card-title">Card Title</span>
          </div>
          <div className="card-content">
            <p>
              I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of
              information. I am convenient because I require little markup
              to use effectively.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="card-action">
            <a href="#">This is a link</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="col s6 m4">
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-image">
            <img
              src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/11/4a/54/fe/essence-restaurant.jpg"
              alt="restaurant one"
              width="400px"
              height="200px"
            />
            <span className="card-title">Card Title</span>
          </div>
          <div className="card-content">
            <p>
              I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of
              information. I am convenient because I require little markup
              to use effectively.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="card-action">
            <a href="#">This is a link</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Oh you right.  But still, add position: relative to it and it should work. I updated my answer with working code.

Comment: ok i will do that. It went to the top but still on top of each other. I wonder if there is something else wrong.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know then.  You're code works perfectly in codepen as is. There is probably something else influencing it.

Comment: I found the error, i had position absolute in some other css file that supposly has no relation to this component. thanks

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  Hope my answer helped you debug it.